# How to configure GCS as filebeat input

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, filebeat, google-cloud-storage

We are storing our audit logs in GCS bucket. we would like to ingest them to Elasticsearch when required - not regularly - using filebeat. I have checked S3 option where it let us use s3 like storages as input using [providers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-aws-s3.html#_provider).

I'm using following configuration but it is not writing any data however when I test the filebeat configuration it is fine however input is stopped working.

Here is warning from logs

```
WARN    [aws-s3]    awss3/config.go:54  neither queue_url nor bucket_arn were provided, input aws-s3 will stop
INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:141   Starting input (ID: 17738867761700079737)
INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:108   Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
INFO    [input.aws-s3]  compat/compat.go:111    Input aws-s3 starting   {"id": "F62D1E3EA5C30879"}
INFO    [input.aws-s3]  compat/compat.go:124    Input 'aws-s3' stopped  {"id": "F62D1E3EA5C30879"}
```

I doubt my input configuration is not right in someway. Please check the following and help me understand what's wrong

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: aws-s3
    non_aws_bucket_name: test-bucket
    number_of_workers: 5
    bucket_list_interval: 300s
    access_key_id: xxxxx    
    secret_access_key: xxxxxxxx
    endpoint: https://storage.googleapis.com

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: "https://es-test-xxx.aivencloud.com"
  username: "avnadmin"
  password: "xxxxx"
  indices:
    - index: 'restore-test'
```

Comment: You are trying to use aws-s3 plugin to fetch logs from Google Cloud bucket. This would not work.

Comment: There seems to be a Google Could module in newer version of filebeat that might be helpful https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.0/filebeat-module-gcp.html

Comment: Yes. @Sniper 
It is available on filebeat-8 & above configuration works fine. thank any how.